# Java Regex with Sets [x, a-b-c, z, b-c, e, f]

Tags: java, regex

I am collecting some values into a set:

```
Set's value:
[x, a-b-c, z, b-c, e, f]
```

So Now, I Iterate thru it to extract some values:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       String Parameter = iterator.next().toString();
       if (Pattern.compile(“Regex??”).matcher(Parameter).find()) {
       do....
```

Here is where I am stuck:

```
What is the correct Regex to find an exact match for a-b-c 
and the Regex to match for b-c.
```

if (Pattern.compile(“Regex to Find a-b-c”).matcher(Parameter).find()) {
do
}

if (Pattern.compile(“Regex to Find b-c”).matcher(Parameter).find()) {
do
}

Comment: why would you need regex for this? you could simply check with `equals` if you are out for the exact literal `a-b-c` and `b-c`

Comment: I agree, with the dummy set it makes a perfect sense. but I had some issues searching for matches using equals and contains. Thanks for your feedback and comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use anchors in-order to do an exact match.

```
^a-b-c$
```

or

```
^b-c$
```

or

matches method.

```
string.matches("a-b-c")
```

Comment: Thanks Raj!! I know string matches makes more sense. but I had issues with it in the past so I decided to go with Regex. Thanks agin for your help!